# ambari yarn memory show more then 100% usage

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hdp

we have ambari cluster with HDP version 2.6.5

from ambari dashboard we see  the following

[image]

we can see that YARN show 111% - this isn't logical value

instead to show X from 100%

what could be the problem here ?